# CAPM and Beta under Prospect Theory

Tags: capm, beta, behavioral-finance

I'm thinking about some sort of behavioral risk factors such as whether different utility functions, such as Prospect Theory according to Kahneman and Tversky, might change the way betas are derived and formulated and whether there are risk factors such as  - say- some sort of loss aversion risk premium and such. From behavioral finance, we already know that there seems to be a pricing impact of lottery-like stock-features aka idiosyncratic positive skewness..

I just wonder whether there are some underlying drivers that might explain the cross section of returns better than the classical risk factors...such as e.g. some "time-inconsistency premium" for assets that pay profits earlier (if hyperbolic discounting is of some importance), some sort of "home bias discount" for stocks that have a large share of local investors holding these or some "loss aversion preium" and "disposition effect factor" etc. pp.

Is there a more "from-scratch-way" to derive some of the factors similar to the CAPM derivation for market Beta? I'm not sure whether my thoughts are totally absurd as a recent chat with Harald Lohre revealed that such behavioral factors are not recognized in the industry yet, however, academics such as David Hirshleifer, with who i also spoke lately, recently published a paper on this topic..(thats why i post it here- curious about your opinion) :-)

PS: sorry for any typos, i'm typing with chubby fingers on my microscopically-small mobile screen

Comment: Examples for behavioural factor models are [Daniel et al. (2020, RFS)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/33/4/1673/5522378?login=true) and [Stambaugh and Yuan (2017, RFS)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/30/4/1270/2965095?login=true). Their factors are similar to those of risk-based models though like [Fama and French (2015, JFE)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304405X14002323) and [Hou et al. (2015, RFS)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/28/3/650/1574802). [1/2]

Comment: Stambaugh and Yuan use a management and a performance factor. They resemble an investment and a profitability factor. Daniel at al. use a long-horizon mispricing and a limited short-term attention factor. They resemble an investment and a momentum factor. Broadly speaking, all these factor models draw from a common set of ``anomalies'' to build their factor models. The academics differ in how they interpret cross-sectional return predictability. The spanning regressions from [Hou et al. (2019, RF)](https://academic.oup.com/rof/article/23/1/1/5133564) show how similar these models are. [2/2]

Comment: @Kevin Yes, thanks a lot. Yes, the paper by Daniel at Alii was the one I had in mind. I also found a few entries on github about someone who built and tested some behavioral factors, however, as she didn't t post her thesis, just the code, it's hard to judge how successful she was. Regarding the other part of my question, I'm still trying to find the answer.. As an avid reader who seem to know the literature (PhD student, right?) do you have some suggestions for me in that direction? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The literature keeps finding new factors and call them anomalies. This goes also for those stemming from behavioral biases. @Kevin provided good answers. Here I simply point out that behavioral theories are great at explaining some anomalies, but not many together. ([Cochrane,(2011,JF)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2011.01671.x)). This does not mean that you can't still capture a behavioral bias in the data, aggregate it at the cross-sectional level and verify if it is anomalous, but what I mean is that it will be difficult to explain it together with other anomalies

Comment: @Matteo Yes, i agree. I am looking at factors that apply to the market, not just focus on firms such as managerial behavior, size, etc. I mean take the disposition effect for example: If a stock is falling, there will be a lot of people who want to hold or even buy more shares. To obtain a market clearing price, some investors need to sell, agreed? Thus, i guess some loss-discount applies until enough investors sell stocks to match the demand for it. Likewise if a stock gains in value and people start selling, some premium seems necessary. Perhaps factors such as momentum capture this already

Comment: Assuming Momentum captures the effect already, my thought is whether momentum is just some sort of instrumental variable that happens to capture the hidden factors sufficiently,.However, if we know , say, the broad majorities or even the marginal investros' utility and beliefs, shouldn't it be possible to design risk factors that reflect this behavior of returns in the market even better? And even if we dream up new fancy factors, are they consistent with the theoretical framework alltogether? I don't want to simply run 2 million factors on a PCA and pick the best matching combination..

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Cochrane article  :-)

Comment: @T123 it's good to hear that there is still someone out there does is reluctant to mine the data :) I see your point about momentum. The point is that that factor is built using information related only to returns, and as such it is likely to incorporate several behavioral effects in it. So if you are thinking in this direction, you might come up with an idea on how to disentangle different behavioral determinants of momentum and see if they add up to its premium over time. I like the idea of Momentum as instrumental variable .

Comment: What I find hard when it comes to behavioral theories is that you necessarily end up with functional forms for preferences that are "off" when compared to the standard and as such you might encounter skepticism on the part of the mainstream. That being said, thinking a bit outside the box is never bad :)

Comment: [This paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3711478) develops a CAPM theory (called $\Pi$-CAPM) using probability weighting as proposed by prospect theory. This might be relevant for you?

Comment: @Kevin thanks a lot for the article, I wasn't aware of this one. Btw, as you seem to know a lot, may I ask your opinion about Haim, Hens and DeGeorgi paper on the Capm and Prospect Theory? They find that the Capm in general still holds given expected moments.. I'll post a link later as I'm working now